# Как удалить строку подсказки (prompt) из консоли?

Tags: python

```
yn = input("Вы хотите начать игру? <y/n>\n")

if yn == "y":
    print("123")
else:
    print("321")
```

Как удалилить строку "Вы хотите начать игру? " из консоли после ввода "y"?

Comment: А что Вы имеете в виду под "НЕ из самого кода"? Строку можно как-то из кода удалить?))

Comment: Я не особо давно в пайтоне просто) И не знаю что от него ожидать. Вдруг он и из кода может.

Comment: Вы наверно имеете ввиду из консоли?

Comment: Да. Извиняюсь что не особо понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно очистить весь экран

```
import  os

yn = input("Вы хотите начать игру? <y/n> ")

if yn == "y":
    # Очистка Win
    os.system('cls')
    # Очистка Linux
    #os.system('clear')
else:
    print("321")
```

Если нужно удалить только последнюю линию, то нужно знать характеристики терминала.

Comment: Можно допилить код, чтобы был единый метод очистки с учетом ОС, например: `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`

Comment: Я не против такого допиливания, но в вопросе не было речи о кроссплатформенности

Comment: `print('\n'*1000)`?

Comment: https://www.csestack.org/clear-python-interpreter-console/

Answer (score 0):

```
print("")
yn = input("Вы хотите начать игру? <y/n>")

if yn == "y":
    print ("\033[A                             \033[A") 
    print("123")
else:
    print ("\033[A                             \033[A") 
    print("321")
```

Сдвигает курсор ввода на строку вверх.
Самую первую строку не удаляет: добавлен print("") вначале :)
Удален \n из вопроса что-бы ответ вводить на той же строке.

Пишут что работает на большинстве консолей. В Repl.it работает.

еще есть спецмодуль для работы с консолью, сам не пробовал.